# html5 video flash fallback advice

Tags: flash, html, video

I am using the html5 video tag and was wondering if you could help answer the following question. When including the different file formats .mp4, .ogg etc do I also have to include a .flv as the flash fallback or does the browser know to automatically default to a flash version?

At the moment I'm only using a .mp4:

```
<video width="300" height="188" type="video/mp4" src="video/video.mp4" controls preload="none" poster="img/test.png">
    </video>
```

Do i need to create the video tag and then have 2 src files, 1 for .mp4 and 1 for .flv?

All advice welcomed.
Kyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

```
<video controls="controls" width="400" height="300" poster="girl.jpg" preload="metadata">
    <source src="beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="beach.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <object id="flowplayer" width="700" height="400" data="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"beach.mp4"}'>
    </object>
    <p>No support at all, download a new version of your browser!</p>
</video>
```

Comment: You should move "No support at all" inside the object element. Also, keep in mind the Flash fallback will never be used in HTML5 browsers, even if they cannot read the videos natively.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you should put the flash fallback inside the video tag.