# FlowPlayer and MP4 not working in IE9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9, mp4, flowplayer

I have the below flash object where I am using FlowPlayer and I want to try and play a .MP4 video.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="450" height="285">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http://localhost:54350/flash/video.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
</object>
```

The only way I have found to get this working for IE7,8, FF & Chrome is by using the flashvar config above and setting an absolute URL in a playlist.

The problem I have is this does not work in Internet Explorer 9.

Does anyone know how to get this working? and possibly a way to not have to use the playlist? I tried setting a "source" and "Src" param but no dice. Maybe someone has a suggested way to use HTML5 Video for IE9 and to fallback to the above for other versions or browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer here: [html5 video flash fallback advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211854/html5-video-flash-fallback-advice)

That does the trick, needs some changes to support autoplay but this is the idea that works for me :-)

```
<video controls="controls" width="450" height="285" preload="metadata">
    <source src="http://localhost:54350/flash/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <object id="flowplayer" width="450" height="285" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"http://localhost:54350/flash/video.mp4"}'>
    </object>
    <p>No video playback capabilities. Download video:</strong> <a href="/flash/video.mp4">MP4 format</a></p>
</video>
```